# Preying on someone's guilt

Tags: single-word-requests

What's a word that describes "to prey on someone's guilt".

Example:

So say, someone accidentally gets their friend killed and they are feeling guilty for the act. Then someone comes and convinces him to kill himself to further their own means.

Comment: That second person could conceivably be ***playing on*** the killer's guilt (M-W [**play on**](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/play-on) *to use a situation or emotions such as fear or worry in order to get what you want*). Or you might say guilt *preyed on the killer's mind*, but it's not idiomatic to use *prey* the way you're suggesting.

Comment: @FumbleFingers I think it is, since he's using it to his own advantage http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/prey+on

Comment: Well, I don't own the English language, so if you think it's idiomatic to use *to prey on someone's guilt* then feel free to do so. I'd ***understand*** what you meant, even if I think it's a non-standard usage.

Comment: @FumbleFingers How about 'feeding on' someone's emotions?

Comment: I'm very familiar with ***prey on someone's guilt***. (Always said it this way - always heard it this way... as opposed to ***"play"*** ) I wonder if it's a regionalism or just malapropism?

Comment: Compare the usages [here](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=played+on+his+guilt%2Cpreyed+on+his+guilt&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cplayed%20on%20his%20guilt%3B%2Cc0) and [here](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=played+on+his+mind%2Cpreyed+on+his+mind&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cplayed%20on%20his%20mind%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cpreyed%20on%20his%20mind%3B%2Cc0). For *his guilt* it's always *play*, and for *his mind* it's nearly always *prey* (but I find *play* acceptable there).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a form of *emotional manipulation*.

In terms of manipulating someone by playing to their guilt, you might consider the verb *guilt-trip*.

From [Oxford Dictionary](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/guilt_trip):

> ***Make (someone) feel guilty, especially in order to induce them to do something.***

Comment: Ah, manipulation would be the keyword I'm looking for, thanks.